# How to list PM2 logs --err --nostream programatically?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I tried:

```
var pm2 = require('pm2');

pm2.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(2);
    }

    pm2.logs(function (err, apps) {
        pm2.disconnect();   // Disconnects from PM2
        if (err) throw err
    });
});
```

but `log` or `logs` function is not defined. I googled a lot but cannot find any API docs regarding `PM2` logging.

Answer (score 0):

When using PM2 programatically there is no such option or method **log** and **logs** I think you can try this link there is method **pm2.reloadLogs(errback)** it will generate logs file here.

${process.name}-${out|err}-${number}.log

https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/reference/pm2-programmatic/

I hope this will help you.

Thank you

Comment: This will only init a log rotation process